# Angular Страница не отображает значения переменной $scope

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Такой вопрос:

```
   <p>{{text}}</p>
```

Это ХТМЛ , который выводит значение скоуп переменной `$scope.text`;

```
   var app = angular.module("MainApp", []);
    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http','$interval', function ($scope,$http,$interval) {
    $scope.text = "Повествование, в отличие от описания, представляет собой изображение событий или явлений, совершающихся не одновременно, а следующих друг за другом или обусловливающих друг друга. Самый, по-видимому, краткий в мировой литературе пример текста повествования – знаменитый рассказ Цезаря: «Пришёл, увидел, победил». Он ярко и точно передаёт суть повествования – это рассказ о том, что произошло, случилось.".`trim()`;
```

Через `alert` отображает корректно. Через вывод на страничку - не отображает.
Angular , апп и контроллер подключен корректно. Вывожу напрямую (не через view).

Comment: По приведенному описанию проблема не воспроизводится: http://plnkr.co/edit/nlEKSujM9MntTrn1C9E1?p=preview Видимо, все же не все подключено корректно.

Comment: Да , вставил на этом ресурсе свой код - заработало. 
А в чем может быть проблема ? 
Я развернул проект на NodeRed , может знаете )